# Spark Out of Memory Error For MapOutputTracker serializeMapStatuses

Tags: apache-spark, emr

I have a spark job which have hundred thousands (300,000 task and more)of tasks at stage 0, and then during the shuffling, the following exception throws on Driver side:

```
util.Utils: Suppressing exception in finally: null 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at 
java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:123) at 
java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:117) at 
java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93) at 
java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153) at 
java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:253) at 
java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:211) at 
java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.write(GZIPOutputStream.java:145) at 
java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeBlockHeader(ObjectOutputStream.java:1894) at 
java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1875) at 
java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:1822) at 
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:719) at 
java.io.ObjectOutputStream.close(ObjectOutputStream.java:740) at 
org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$serializeMapStatuses$2.apply$mcV$sp(MapOutputTracker.scala:618) at 
org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1319) at 
org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.serializeMapStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:617) at 
org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerMaster.getSerializedMapOutputStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:560) at 
org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerMaster$MessageLoop.run(MapOutputTracker.scala:349) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I checked ByteArrayOutputStream code, and it throws out of memory error when the array size is larger than INTEGER.MAX which is about 2G. That means the map status serialization result should less than 2G.

I also checked the MapOutputTracker code, this map status size is related to task size and following stage task size.

I was wondering if anyone encounter this issue, how you resolve this. my understanding is we can only reduce the size of task, but my task can only stucks because less partition will delay the computation.

Comment: This is not the regarding the heap size. as you can see, it doesn't say heap size is not enough. if you check the logic on ByteArrayOutputStream, it's just because the serialized data is exceeded the JVM array limitation.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by a single block that exceeds 2GB of memory during a shuffle. This usually means your operation requires larger parallelism which will reduce the size of any individual block - hopefully below the 2GB limit (which is extremely high.)

**No Spark shuffle block can be greater than 2 GB**

Spark uses ByteBuffer as abstraction for storing blocks.

```
  val buf =ByteBuffer.allocate(length.toInt)

  ByteBuffer is limited by Integer.MAX_IZE(2GB)
```

**Increasing your Parallelism**

1) Repartition your data before invoking the operation that causes this error as follows:

```
DataFrame.repartition(400)
RDD.repartition(400)
```

2) Pass the number of partitions into the operation as the last argument (where supported):

```
 import org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions
 RDD.groupByKey(numPartitions: Int) RDD.join(other: RDD, numPartitions:Int)
```

3) Set the default parallelism (partitions) through the SparkConf as follows (NOT YET SUPPORTED in Databricks Cloud):

```
// create the SparkConf used to create the SparkContext val conf = new SparkConf()
// set the parallelism/partitions conf.set("spark.default.parallelism", 400)

// create the SparkContext with the conf val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

// check the parallelism/partitions sc.defaultParallelism
```

4) Set the SQL partitions through SQL as follows (default is 200):

SET spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=400;

**Why 2GB?**

This limit exists because of the limit on Java Integers: 2^31 == 2,147,483,647 ~= 2GB.

Spark's shuffle mechanism currently uses Java ByteArrays to transport the data across the network.

This will be enhanced in the future by either expanding Spark's shuffle to use either a larger ByteArrays using Longs, chaining together ByteArrays, or both.

https://forums.databricks.com/questions/1140/im-seeing-an-outofmemoryerror-requested-array-size.html

Comment: If you notice the stack trace, I don't think it's related spark.sql.shuffle.partitions. org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1319) at 
org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.serializeMapStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:617) at 
org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerMaster.getSerializedMapOutputStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:560). it's related to serializing the map status in MapoutputTracker which contains the block size information for each reduce id.